# ElasticSearch: When using field collapsing is it possible to return all documents that do not have a value for the collapse key?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to collapse documents on a given key, ordered by date. The key is not always populated. In cases where the key is null, elastic seems to collapse all documents that do not have this key populated and return the newest one. I would like to only collapse documents were the field is populated and return the document if the key isn't present. Is this possible?

Here is the collapse query I am currently using:

```
"collapse": {
"field": "COLLAPSE_KEY",
"inner_hits": {
  "name": "collapse_inner_hit",
  "ignore_unmapped": false,
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1,
  "version": false,
  "seq_no_primary_term": false,
  "explain": false,
  "track_scores": false,
  "sort": [
    {
      "DATE_FIELD": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and in java:

```
 CollapseBuilder collapseBuilder = new CollapseBuilder(COLLAPSE_KEY);

 InnerHitBuilder collapseHitBuilder = new InnerHitBuilder("collapse_inner_hit");
 collapseHitBuilder.setSize(1);
 collapseHitBuilder.addSort(new FieldSortBuilder(DATE_FIELD).order(SortOrder.DESC));
 collapseBuilder.setInnerHits(collapseHitBuilder);

 searchSourceBuilder.collapse(collapseBuilder);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In absence of value elastic will collapse them under 'null'. If those values are not required in response - consider adding a [exists](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) clause to the query.

Comment: Apologies if it wasn't clear. They are required, that's my issue.

Comment: Since collapse does not support scripted fields ( it needs actual field in the document) - there is no other workaround using collapsed fields.